# Return a collect type in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I dont know hot to get a Collect Type in query sentece.
for example

I defined my type and all...

When i do:

```
   SELECT 
   MyType(att1,att2)
   FROM 
   table
```

it return

|att1 | att2 |

| a   | b    |

| c   |  d   |

.
.

When i do:

```
   SELECT 
   MyTABLE_COLLECT_TYPE (MyType(att1,att2))
   FROM 
   table
```

it return

|MyTABLE_COLLECT_TYPE |

|collection   |

|collection   |

.
.

And each collection have one record MyType(att1,att2)

So my questio is how i can get only one collection of all type MyType(att1,att2), a single row that return the whole table. ( I dont want to use a function if it possible :P )

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need use **TABLE(t.collection_field)**

see [Unnesting Results of Collection Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#i454908)

example from the link above:

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM department_persons d, TABLE(d.dept_emps) e;

IDNO NAME PHONE
---------- ------------------------------ ---------------
1 John Smith 1-650-555-0135
2 Diane Smith 1-650-555-0135
```

extended sample from the link above

```
CREATE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  name           VARCHAR2(30),
  phone          VARCHAR2(20),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER, 
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_details ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY person_typ ) );

CREATE TYPE BODY person_typ AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN idno;
  END;
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_details ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY person_typ ) IS
  BEGIN
    -- use the put_line procedure of the DBMS_OUTPUT package to display details
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(idno) || ' - '  || name || ' - '  || phone);
  END;
END;


CREATE TYPE people_typ AS TABLE OF person_typ; -- nested table type


CREATE TABLE department_persons (
  dept_no    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  dept_name  CHAR(20),
  dept_mgr   person_typ DEFAULT person_typ(10,'John Doe',NULL),
  dept_emps  people_typ DEFAULT people_typ() ) -- instance of nested table type
  NESTED TABLE dept_emps STORE AS dept_emps_tab;

INSERT INTO department_persons VALUES 
   ( 101, 'Physical Sciences', person_typ(65,'Vrinda Mills', '1-650-555-0125'),
           people_typ( person_typ(1, 'John Smith', '1-650-555-0135'), 
                        person_typ(2, 'Diane Smith', NULL) ) );
INSERT INTO department_persons VALUES 
  ( 104, 'Life Sciences', person_typ(70,'James Hall', '1-415-555-0101'), 
    people_typ() ); -- an empty people_typ table
```

`select * from    department_persons` 
return **Collection** as in your description

```
    DEPT_NO DEPT_NAME   DEPT_MGR.IDNO   DEPT_MGR.NAME   DEPT_MGR.PHONE  DEPT_EMPS
1   101 Physical Sciences       65  Vrinda Mills    1-650-555-0125  <Collection>
2   104 Life Sciences           70  James Hall  1-415-555-0101  <Collection>
```

if you add **TABLE** you have what you need

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM department_persons d, TABLE(d.dept_emps) e;

    IDNO    NAME    PHONE
1   1   John Smith  1-650-555-0135
2   2   Diane Smith
```